# How can I create a timetable using tableview?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am going to create a timetable in xcode, and will put in my lessons etc. at school.

I want to have a static header, as well as a static left column (which will be a lot smaller than the other one). And how do I get this editable, so the user can make it personal?

In more detail:
It will be as a normal timetable. I will have a main menu, which will consist of buttons, and all the days of the week. e.g:
Monday (-----) this will then link to a new view controller where it is a left column (which is pretty tiny). In that left column the *time* of the lesson will be. In the right column, which is bigger, the *lesson* and the teacher you're having will be in column. I also want there to be an edit button, so the user of the timetable can put in *their* lessons and which time they will be.

Same with the other days.

I am following this [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) on how to make a horizontal table.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure this is a correct tutorial for you. It seems your table dimensions will be static, e.g. 5-7 columns representing the days of week and some number of rows representing the hours or am I wrong? Anyway it would be best to describe what you are trying to achieve and where is your issue. Also what do you mean by editable? Being able to drag the cells around or to input some text...?

Comment: I have edited the question, and hopefully it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: So the first controller is pretty much straight forward making 5 views with days inserted. The second one seems to be a completely normal table view with costume cells. I suggest you to have a custom data structure consisting of time and description (can even be a subclass of table view cell). A view displaying this data should have the array of these items. When array is updated, sort the array by time, reload the table view where datasource objects are all from the array: Section count = 1, row count = array.count...

Comment: Every table will be only two columns, like this (just the Monday part): http://www.calendarpedia.co.uk/images/timetable.png (can't post images yet). Could you try clarifying how I should do that?

Comment: I see 6 columns on this image

Comment: Yes I know, but if you ignore the other columns, except for Monday and the Time/period column. It was meant to show something similar to what I wanted. Like this: http://blog.rockymountaintraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/fig2.jpg